# Todo conteúdo que coloco no site não sai do header

Tags: html, css

Fiz um header e quando coloco o conteúdo do site, mesmo fora da tag , o conteúdo permanece lá. Como eu poderia resolver?

O código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html/>
<html lang="pt-br">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head><title>NAV TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav3.2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <script src="nav.js"></script> -->
    <header>
        <img class="logo" src="logo4.png" alt="logo" width="265px" height="49px">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loja</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contato</button>
        </a>
    </header>
    <div id="teste">
        <h1> teste </h1>x
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    <style> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500');
</style>

nav {
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
}

head, body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252A;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: auto;}

.nav__links {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav__links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__links li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
    color: #0088a9
}

button {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#teste {
    text-align: left
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Aqui está um print:
[image: A Página:]

Comment: Você abriu a tag <html> duas vezes

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente eu corrigi o ; que estava faltando no teste:

```
#teste {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

E apaguei o x que estava sobrando:

```
<div id="teste">
        <h1> teste </h1>
    </div>
```

Depois disso retirei o background-color de * que é um seletor para tudo e coloquei apenas no header. Agora o conteúdo terá o background que quiser.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  background-color: #24252a;
}
```